# redhat apache web server configuration

Tags: linux, web-server, redhat, httpd

I log into a new server as root.
Once I log in I su username which allows me to choose test or production.

When I choose test I run httpd -v from the bash prompt and get the apache version

What confuses me is when i run server httpd restart I get httpd server not found.

How can it recognize httpd -v and not a restart.  Ohh fyi, this is a new server with no sites on it.

Comment: can you please share the log output of /var/log/messages and /var/log/secure. also share the error. Anshul

Comment: ok, it will take me a little bit to get the log messages...not very good at this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just open three simultaneously windows and perform below tasks:

1. tail -f /var/log/messages
2. tail -f /var/log/secure
3. start the apache server

send the result and logs with error while restarting the apache server.

Comment: Last message in the messages and secure logs was from Dec 16th.  It's not recording my bash commands.  When performing  "server httpd restart" the error message is "server: command is not found"

Comment: try "service httpd restart"

Answer (score 0):

BY default the service cannot be start or stop by non-root user because of security risk. but you can run Apache as any user by allocating proper resources

The standard http port 80 (which is priviledged) you will have to setup, as root a redirection to your real Apache server. The easiest way is probably using iptables. For example if your Apache server is listening on port 8080:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 --syn -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

If you can not configure the server like this. the same can be configured to a non privileged port and access it using an URL that looks like http://www.localdomain:8080/